# How to hide/show column based on if statement using Material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, show-hide

I have the following code, and I want to hide or show the TableCell based on if statement, how do I do that?

I am using MATERIAL-UI : https://material-ui.com/

```
  <TableBody>
                {Object.entries(servicesCode).map(([key, value]) => (
                  servicesValueTotal[key] = ((servicesValue[key] + servicesTaxe[key])),
                  <TableRow key={servicesCode[key]}>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {key}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center" >{servicesCode[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesValue[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesTaxe[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesValueTotal[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesTec[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesClient[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesStatus[key]}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the feature called conditional rendering?

`{condition && <Component />}`, 
for example `{condition && <TableCell align="center" >{servicesCode[key]}</TableCell>}`

Note: As You are using a table to display data, it should have fixed number of `th` tags - table headings, thus removing table cells completely might be a bad solution.

You could also leave the table cell empty based on conditon like 
`<TableCell align="center" >{condition && servicesCode[key]}</TableCell>` or like `<TableCell align="center" >{condition ? someVariable : "No data here"}</TableCell>`

Comment: I'm new at this, some thing like   ´{ if (filters.user_id!=null) && <TableCell align="center">{servicesCode[key]}</TableCell>}´ work?

Comment: When using inline logical operator the `if` statement is not necessary. Instead something like this would do the trick `{ filters.user_id!=null && <TableCell align="center">{servicesCode[key]}</TableCell>}`. Please see [Conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) .

Answer (score 4):

```js
let showTableCell = (true) ? true : false; // you can have a single line condition or multiple line condition using if and else here.

 <TableBody>
                {Object.entries(servicesCode).map(([key, value]) => (
                  servicesValueTotal[key] = ((servicesValue[key] + servicesTaxe[key])),
                  <TableRow key={servicesCode[key]}>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {key}
                    </TableCell>
                    {showTableCell && <TableCell align="center" >{servicesCode[key]}</TableCell>}
                    // or you could also add condition here as well
                    {showTableCell ? <TableCell align="center">{servicesValue[key]}</TableCell> : "Some other data here"}
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesTaxe[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesValueTotal[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesTec[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesClient[key]}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{servicesStatus[key]}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
```